# Magento Test Automation Framework

Tags: magento, automated-tests

I am able to finish the installation process successfully.

Currently I am trying to run the scripts from MTAF. I am following the process and procedures mentioned in the Installation and User guide. But at the moment, I am not able to run any of the automated scripts. I am getting different messages like - "No test cases executed" / "Perhaps an error occurred. See the output window". For your reference, [image][image][image][image][image][image]I have attached the main screen prints for the configurations I am using.

It would be of much help if you can point me to some person or group wherein I can get  some help/directions to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Corresponding to your setting on the *2nd screen*, you have to change it from *runtests.bat* to path of PhpUnit execution file (*../pear/phpunit.bat*)

Additionally, you need specify in 'Project properties' -> 'PhpUnit configuration' -> 'Use bootstrap' + 'Use XML Configuration' references to *../mtaf/bootstrap.php* and *../mtaf/phpunit.xml* respectively.

It will be enough to run tests.